# Why do we omit coefficients of polynomial terms when feature mapping?

Tags: machine-learning, polynomials

I've been studying the Machine Learning course on Coursera by Andrew Ng.
I've solved the programming assignment that is given at the end of the week 3. But there was something that I was wondering and I do not want to skip things without being able to reason them, at least I couldn't.

Why do we omit coefficients of polynomial terms when feature mapping?

I quote from the assignment's [PDF](https://www.docdroid.net/Rmy7OHR/ex2.pdf#page=9) (which you can view from the link).

> **2.2 Feature mapping**
>
> One way to fit the data better is to create more features from each data
>   point. In the provided function mapFeature.m, we will map the features into
>   all polynomial terms of x 1 and x 2 up to the sixth power.
>
> [image: mapFeature]

As you can see coefficients are not included.
Considering I am not good at math I think we found all the polynomial terms doing:

[image]

since here we would get coefficients after we take the powers, why do we omit them in the vector?

By coefficients I mean coefficients of the terms

[image]

[image] instead of [image] in the vector.

Comment: I'm not sure what coefficients are we talking about?

Comment: Coefficients of the terms. Like 2x1x2 instead of x1x2 in the vector. Well, I will edit that part to be clear.